# Any way to add videos into Roblox studio for a game?

Tags: video, roblox

I'm trying to make a game on Roblox where you are a camera director set in a 1950's movie theater and you have to try and sneak propaganda into the movie the perfect amount of times so you don't get fired and I want to make it so I can play a video on the screen but I have no clue how. Any help?

Comment: Consider looking into another game development environment. ROBLOX does not currently support videos inside games and as of writing does not have any plans to either.

Answer (score 1):

You can make several decals and a script to swap between them in a loop, i don't think there is a real video option.

Answer (score 0):

Roblox has been working on a ViewPortFrame instance, which is a GUIObject that will allow game developers to include videos in their games, how cool is that? Sadly, as far as I know roblox wiki has not got a article about this. We'll have to wait until they make one.